# How to write a method that takes in a List of Integer, Float, Double and calculate the average?

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream

I am trying to write a method that takes in a list of numeric values - eg `List<Integer>`, `List<Float>`, `List<Double>` etc - and give me the average.

```
public double getAverage(List<? extends Number> stats) {
    double sum = 0.00;
    if(!stats.isEmpty()) {
        // sum = stats.stream()
        //            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
        // return sum / stats.size();
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'capture<? extends java.lang.Number>', 'capture<? extends java.lang.Number>'

Comment: [Number::doubleValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **OptionalDouble average()**
>
> Where, OptionalDouble is a container object  which may or may not
> contain a double value.

```
  public class Test {

    public static OptionalDouble getAverage(List<? extends Number> stats) {
        return stats.
                stream().
                 mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue()).
                    average();
            
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 5, 67, 3);
        if(getAverage(list).isPresent());
        {
            Double average = getAverage(list).getAsDouble();
            System.out.println(average);
        }
        
    }
}
```

or

Using Goolge [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/31.0.1-jre)

```
 Double averge = Stats.meanOf(list);
```

it gets syntactically simplified

Answer (score 10):

Create a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) from `Number` objects via [`Number#doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue()), then use available reduction methods to calculate the average:

```
public double getAverage(List<? extends Number> stats) {
    return stats.stream()
      .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
      .summaryStatistics() // small overhead of unnecessary arithmetic
      .getAverage(); // returns 0 when empty
}
```

or

```
public double getAverage(List<? extends Number> stats) {
    return stats.stream()
      .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
      .average()
      .orElse(0); // explicit value for empty (but no other value makes sense)
}
```

depending on which style you prefer.

Comment: `.average() .orElse(0)` is preferable, as it doesn’t waste resources to calculate minimum and maximum, just to drop the information afterwards. Also, it makes explicit what happens for an empty list.